# How to Add an optionset filter criteria in MS CRM Query Expression?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, query-expressions

I have an entity LeaveType with two attributes, 1. Type, 2. Available Days, where Type is an optionset and Available days is a text field. I want to fetch all such LeaveType records where the Type = 'Annual' selected in the optionset. I am not able to find how to add a filter the query expression for the option set value. Below is my in progress method:

```
public Entity Getleavetype(Guid LeaveDetailsId, IOrganizationService _orgService, CodeActivityContext Acontext)
        {
            QueryExpression GetLeavedetails = new QueryExpression();
            GetLeavedetails.EntityName = "sgfdhr_leavetype";
            GetLeavedetails.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_type");
            GetLeavedetails.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_availabledays");
            GetLeavedetails.Criteria.AddCondition("new_type", ConditionOperator.Equal,   "Annual" ); //Is this correct????
            GetLeavedetails.Criteria.AddCondition("new_employeeleavecalculation", ConditionOperator.Equal, LeaveDetailsId); //ignore this

            //((OptionSetValue)LeaveDetailsId["new_leavetype"]).Value

            EntityCollection LeaveDetails = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(GetLeavedetails);
            return LeaveDetails[0];
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

In your condition you need to set the integer value of the optionset, not the label.

Assuming that `Annual` value is for example 2, the code will be:

```
GetLeavedetails.Criteria.AddCondition("new_type", ConditionOperator.Equal, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks Guido. Can you also help me with this code

<code>
  string value = ((OptionSetValue)LeaveDetails["new_leavetype"]).Value.toString(); // 
</code>
I need to get the string value of the option set, not the integer value.

Comment: for the label you need to query the metadata, an example here: http://nishantrana.me/2010/12/24/get-value-for-optionset-in-crm-2011/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RetrieveAttributeRequest` to find an int value of `OptionSet` text.

In my code it looks like:

```
private static int findParkedOptionValue(IOrganizationService service)
{
    RetrieveAttributeRequest attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest
    {
        EntityLogicalName = Model.Invite.ENTITY_NAME,
        LogicalName = Model.Invite.COLUMN_STATUS,
        RetrieveAsIfPublished = false
    };

    // Execute the request
    RetrieveAttributeResponse attributeResponse =
        (RetrieveAttributeResponse)service.Execute(attributeRequest);
    var attributeMetadata = (EnumAttributeMetadata)attributeResponse.AttributeMetadata;

    // Get the current options list for the retrieved attribute.
    var optionList = (from o in attributeMetadata.OptionSet.Options
                      select new { Value = o.Value, Text = o.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label }).ToList();
    int value = (int)optionList.Where(o => o.Text == "Парковка")
                                .Select(o => o.Value)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
    return value;

}
```

In https://community.dynamics.com/enterprise/b/crmmemories/archive/2017/04/20/retrieve-option-set-metadata-in-c you found a perfect example.